# Why doesn't this Cloudant/couchdb $regex query work?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to pull (and delete) all records from our database that *don't* have a URL with the word 'box' in it.  This is the query I'm using:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "$not": {
         "url": {
            "$regex": ".*box.*"
         }
      }
   },
   "limit": 50
}
```

This query returns no records. But if I remove the $not, I get all records that *do* have the word 'box' in the url, but that's the opposite of what I want.  Why do I get no results when adding the $not?

I have tried adding a simple base to the query like "_id":{"$gte":0} but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

from the [Cloudant doc](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html):

> You can create more complex selector expressions by combining
>   operators. However, for Cloudant NoSQL DB Query indexes of type json,
>   you cannot use 'combination' or 'array logical' operators such as
>   $regex as the basis of a query.

`$not` is a [combination operator](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#combination-operators) and therefore cannot be the basis of a query

i am able to get the following to work:

**index**

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["url"]
    },
    "name" : "url-json-index",
    "type" : "json"
}
```

**query**

```
{
   "selector": {
      "url": {
         "$not": {
            "$regex": ".*box.*"
         }
      }
   },
   "limit": 50,
   "use_index": "url-json-index"
}
```

if you are still seeing problems, can you provide the output from `_/explain` and the indexes you have in place.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I still cannot get it to work, however.  I already had a JSON index for the url field, along with a full-text index and a JSON index on another field.  Here is the output of explain (in multiple comments due to comment size limitations):

Comment: {
 "dbname": "eeed3510-e6c7-4d57-85e4-fa34a53ba0ab-bluemix/david_test_custom_answers",
 "index": {
  "ddoc": "_design/32372935e14bed00cc6db4fc9efca0f1537d34a8",
  "name": "32372935e14bed00cc6db4fc9efca0f1537d34a8",
  "type": "text",
  "def": {
   "default_analyzer": "keyword",
   "default_field": {},
   "selector": {},
   "fields": [],
   "index_array_lengths": true
  }
 },
...

Comment: ...

 "selector": {
  "url": {
   "$not": {
    "$regex": ".*box.*"
   }
  }
 },
 "opts": {
  "use_index": [],
  "bookmark": [],
  "limit": 50,
  "skip": 0,
  "sort": {},
  "fields": "all_fields",
  "r": [
   49
  ],
  "conflicts": false,
  "stale": false,
  "update": true,
  "stable": false,
  "execution_stats": false
 },
 "limit": 50,
 "skip": 0,
 "fields": "all_fields",
 "query": "((($fieldnames:url_3a*) OR ($fieldnames:url.*)) AND NOT (($fieldnames:url_3astring)))",
 "sort": "relevance"
}

Comment: I am sorry to say I am not proficient in this and don't know how to read the explain output.

Comment: @DavidPowell, from the explain the query is using index `"name": "32372935e14bed00cc6db4fc9efca0f1537d34a8"` which is a `text` index (and probably not the index you are not wanting). you can try to have it use the json index or some other specific index by including `"use_index": "<name_of_index_to_use>"` see my edited example above. you can learn more about explain plans and how indexes are chosen here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#explain-plans

Comment: Everything you say makes perfect sense, but I still can get no joy from this query. I created a json index called url-json-index, exactly like you did above. Then I copypasted your query into the dashboard query field and clicked "Run Query".  The dashboard immediately returned an error banner that said "Error running query. Reason: (unknown_error) Unknown Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,no_index_matching_name}".  I viewed the index under "manage indexes" on the dashboard, and it showed it but without the name.   Perhaps the dashboard has a problem with naming indexes?

Answer (score 1):

The "no results" issue is due to a bug in text indexes that has been recently fixed. However, neither `$not` nor `$regex` operators are able to take advantage of global indexes so will always result in a full database or index scan.

The way to optimise this query is to use a [partial index](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#creating-a-partial-index). A partial index filters documents at indexing time rather than at query time, creating an index over a subset of the database. You then need to tell the `_find` endpoint to explicitly use the partial index. For example, create an index which only includes documents not matching your regex:

```
POST /<db>/_index
{
  "index": {
    "partial_filter_selector": {
      "url": {
         "$not": {
            "$regex": ".*box.*"
         }
      }
    },
    "fields": ["type"]
  },
  "ddoc" : "url-not-box",
  "type" : "json"
}
```

then at query time:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "url": {
         "$not": {
            "$regex": ".*box.*"
         }
      }
   },
   "limit": 50,
   "use_index": "url-not-box"
}
```

You can see how many documents are scanned to fulfil the query in the Cloudant UI - the execution statistics are displayed in a popup underneath the query text area.

You may also find this [This article](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/creating-partial-cloudant-indexes-1ebf169c8e15) about partial indexes helpful.